# get html attribute value by name react native render html

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

I am trying to get the src value from the html string `<video src="url"></video>`. I need the source value so I can custom render the component using the renderers prop for the default export. The package is `react-native-render-html`

```
video: (src: any) => {
  console.error(src);
  return(
    <Video
      source={{uri: "https://url"}}
      style={{ width: 100, height: 100, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
      resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
      shouldPlay={false}
      isLooping
      isMuted
      useNativeControls
    />
  )
},
```

the source object does not contain the attribute value of src thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is stored in `obj['tnode'].domNode.attribs.src`. NOTE: i made a loop to show what properties are available

```js
video: (obj1: any, obj2: any) => {
    let link
    for (var property in obj1) {
        if (property === 'tnode') {
            console.log(property, 'property', obj1[property].domNode.attribs.src, 'src[property]');
            link = obj1[property].domNode.attribs.src;
        }
    }
    return (<Video
                                        
                                        source={{uri: link}}
                                        style={{ width: isFullScreen ? width : width / 4, height: isFullScreen ? height : height as number / 4, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
                                        resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
                                        shouldPlay={true}
                                        isLooping
                                        isMuted
                                        useNativeControls
                                    />)
},
```